# asynchronous code in an Angular guard doesn't open page

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-guards

The setup is simple. I have a guard that guards a route. If the user's property `locationSaved === true` then we want to allow the user to enter the page.

If the first check of the browser token is false we want to make an HTTP request to see if maybe the most recent version of the user object's locationSaved property might be updated to true.

I did the server request and it returned true, so I expected it to open the page, but unfortunately it doesn't. I assume it has something to do with the asynchronous request I did in the page, because when I replace the server request code with a simple `return true`; then it does open the page.

Does anyone know how I can use this asynchronous request and navigate to the page if the server returns true?

**This is my guard code. I set up so that it would make the asynchronous request and the server returned true. However, it doesn't navigate to the page.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from './auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log('entered the guard');
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      if (this.authService.currentUser().user.locationSaved) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.authService.isLocationSaved()
          .subscribe((status: {saved: boolean}) => {
            console.log('saved', status);
            return status.saved;
          });
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't because in the else block, you're not returning anything. Instead of `subscribe`ing, you should have `map`ped to `status.saved`

Ofcourse, the `canActivate` method will now return a `boolean` or an `Observable<boolean>`. So you might want to change the return type of `canActivate`.

This should work:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      if (this.authService.currentUser().user.locationSaved) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return this.authService.isLocationSaved()
          .pipe(map(status => status.saved));
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It now display the error `type Observable<any> is not assignable to type 'boolean

Comment: You'll have to change the return type to `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean>`. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Great, it works fine now. Thanks for the quick help!